# How to add futon (not fauxton) to CouchDB

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, fauxton

Fauxton is nice and shiny, but it is missing at least one critical feature for working with CouchDB:  browsing a document's revision history. The database permission interface also managed to create a mess of my database.

Is there any way to get the old futon running on CouchDB 2.x?

Comment: I am guessing you mean that the URL for Futon in CouchDb 1.x now points to Fauxton in CouchDb 2.x? I like Fauxton but I would also be interested to know if Futon still exists in CouchDb 2.

Comment: You can probably take the futon app from 1.7.1 and move it to the fauxton folder in Couch 2.x.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use futon with CouchDB 1.x version.

CouchDB Team decided to use it as a default web-based interface & included with CouchDB 2.x. Fauxton is a native web-based interface built into CouchDB.

https://couchdb.apache.org/fauxton-visual-guide/

Comment: I want(ed) futon on Couch 2.x (this is from 3 years ago!)